# 401 response when using Xamarin and IdentityModel to WebAPI secured by IdentityServer 3

Tags: asp.net-web-api, xamarin, identityserver3

I am having an identical problem to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40089138/identity-server-bearer-token-authentication-how-to-trace-failed-authorizatio) but their solution doesn't work for me.

I'm calling a WebAPI method (.Net 4.5.2) and the project has a reference to IdentityModel 1.13.1 and it is protected using IdentityServer 3 with the following code in the startup class -

```
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

        app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = "https://localhost:44305/core/",
            RequiredScopes = new[] { "read", "write" },

            // client credentials for the introspection endpoint
            ClientId = "clientcredentials.client",
            ClientSecret = "secret"
        });
```

The clients configuration in the IdentityServer startup includes the following client definition -

```
new Client
            {
                ClientName = "Mobile Api Client",
                Enabled = true,
                ClientId = "clientcredentials.client",
                Flow = Flows.ClientCredentials,

                ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>
                    {
                        new Secret("secret".Sha256()),
                        new Secret
                        {
                            Value = "[valid thumbprint]",
                            Type = "X509Thumbprint",
                            Description = "Client Certificate"
                        },
                    },

                AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                    {
                        "read",
                        "write"
                    },

                Claims = new List<Claim>
                    {
                        new Claim("location", "datacenter")
                    }
            }
```

And in the Xamarin client (which also uses IdentityModel 1.13.1) ...

```
            var token = IdentityServerClient.RequestClientToken();  // this returns a valid bearer token
            TokenResultLabel.Text = token.Raw;

            HttpClient apiClient = new HttpClient();

            apiClient.SetBearerToken(token.AccessToken);
            var result = await apiClient.GetStringAsync("[valid api URL]");
            ApiResultLabel.Text = result;
```

I've tried it with IdentityModel 2.0 (latest compatible version), 1.13.1 (the version mentioned in the referenced question, and 1.9.2 (the version in the IdentityServer 3 samples)

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You need to turn on logging in your API - https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/consuming/diagnostics.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I had already tried this however the log file wasn't being generated.  In the end I gave up and recreated the WebAPI project from scratch but this time I used the blank web project template and added just the WebAPI references, previously I had used the MVC template with WebAPI references.  I don't know what the differences are but it's working.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

While the configuration allows the client to request both the `read` and `write` scopes, do you explicitly specify when you request the access token that you wish to get one containing these 2 scopes? This should happen in your `IdentityServerClient.RequestClientToken` method.

Allowing a client to request scopes doesn't mean these scopes will automatically be included in access tokens returned by IdentityServer.